# About rerendering and navigating back from one page to another page

Tags: next.js, react-hooks, rerender

I'm facing one issue. i'm getting bug in my website. in my website there is one minicart. in that minicart all carts items should be shown. there is also one checkout button in down if i click on that checkout button it'll redirect me to checkout page.

once i went there there is some recommended products. if i add that recommended products from  checkout and then i get back to the minicart its not visible which i have added from the checkout page. then after i refresh the page its showing the recent added product. i don't know why is it happening. how can i resolve this issue?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Please provide some code so we can help you debug your issue.

Comment: And please start using things like capital letters, `.` and `,` etc.